# display images in image slider sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

> in my sharepoint home page am using a image slider. so am saved some images in this path C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\images. so in this folder there are some images. but in browser am getting only 2 images. Remaining images are not displaying.Means they are appering as some crashed image. but in folder am able to all the images. but in browser only 2 images(new and mutual) are displaying,other 3.jpg and 1.jpg are not displaying.

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8 can" >
                <div id="featured-slider">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="../../images/new.jpg" class="img-responsive"  alt=""/>                        </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="../../images/mutual.jpg" class="img-responsive"  alt=""/>                        </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="../../images/3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>                        </a>
                        <a href="#">
                        <img src="../../images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>                        </a>                    </div>
          </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your  tags are missing the closing .

Also, you might try changing the names of 3.jpg and 1.jpg because SharePoint might have trouble with those names in this context.